# XSL outputting more than expected

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm fairly new to XSLT and XPath and have been banging my head against the wall for a while on this problem.

I have the following XML:

```
<reply>
    <multi-results>
        <multi-item>
            <name>node1</name>
            <information>
                <block>
                    <slot>A</slot>
                    <state>Online</state>
                    <colour>purple</colour>
                </block>
                <block>
                    <slot>B</slot>
                    <state>Online</state>
                    <colour>yellow</colour>
                </block>
                <block>
                    <slot>C</slot>
                    <state>Online</state>
                    <colour>red</colour>
                </block>
                <block>
                    <slot>D</slot>
                    <state>Online</state>
                    <colour>blue</colour>
                </block>
            </information>
        </multi-item>
    </multi-results>
    <address>
        <label>this is an arbitrary bit of text included for this example</label>
    </address>
</reply>
```

There are a variable number of "block" entries per file.

I want to "CSV" the data, and I'm using the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
    <xsl:template match="block">
        <xsl:value-of select="slot"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="colour"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
node1A|Online|purple
B|Online|yellow
C|Online|red
D|Online|blue
this is an arbitrary bit of text included for this example
```

However, the output includes both the "name" and the "label"...

I want only what I'm explicitly asking for in the XSL:

```
A|Online|purple
B|Online|yellow
C|Online|red
D|Online|blue
```

I don't understand why. Can someone explain please?

Also, there may be multiple "name" elements, each with its own number of "block" elements.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements outside the `<block>` are being processed using the default template rules. To prevent this you need to add

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="block"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you don't need the template rules that match text nodes, because you never apply-templates to text nodes.

Comment: This is much cleaner solution. By the way, I learned XSLT with your book, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove xsl:value-of from your first xsl:template. You get "name" and "label" contents because of it: it takes any text node and outputs its content. Moreover you don't need checking conditions on text nodes, leave one xsl:template for them with empty body:

```
 <xsl:template match="*/text()"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not clear on what you mean... When you say the "first" template, do you mean the `<xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">` ??

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. I need to remove the `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>`... Many thanks!